# What is rack in ruby? What is puma in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rack, puma

According to the definition, the puma is kind of web server and the rack is an interface between web server and application server.

But, lots of videos mention that rack is a interface between web framework and web server. So can I interpret that we use web framework to build our application, so the rack is an interface between web framework and web server?

Another question is that if puma is kind of web server, can I use Apache or Nginx to replace it?

Comment: I found an article about deploying a rails app with Puma and Nginx. It said, "as Puma is not designed to be accessed by users directly, we will use Nginx as a reverse proxy that will buffer requests and responses between users and your Rails application." Why is puma can be accessed by the user directly?

Answer (score 11):

Puma is an application server, more specifically a [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) app server. (There are more than just Puma: Unicorn, Passenger etc. There are also application servers for different interfaces; for example, Tomcat and JBoss are Java application servers.) An application server accepts a HTTP request, parses it into a structure in the application's language, hands it off to the application, and awaits a response object which it then returns to the client.

Nginx/Apache are general purpose web servers. Apache does not know how to serve Rack applications, and Puma doesn't know how to do a bunch of other things Nginx/Apache do (e.g. CGI scripts, URL rewriting, proxies, balancing, blacklisting...)

Rack is a library for Ruby that accepts parsed HTTP requests from an app server, funnels them through a configurable stack of middleware (such as e.g. session handling) passing the request object to a handler, and returning the response object the app server, making web development in Ruby easy. You can execute a Rack app directly (or rather, with a very simple server that is installed with Rack), but it is not recommended outside development, which is where "proper" application servers come in: they know how to keep your app alive, restart it if it dies, guarantee that there is the predetermined number of threads running, things like that.

Thus, typically, you have your Web server accept connections, then using [simple reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html#simple) pass the appropriate requests to your Rack application, which is executing inside the Rack app server. This gives you the benefits from all the involved pieces.

Comment: Rack doesn't parse HTTP. That's what the app server does. Rack gets a request (including parsed HTTP headers in a Ruby Hash), handles it through various middlewares and finally hands it over to the application (e.g. a Rails app). which again returns a Ruby object. The application server in turn converts that to an HTTP response and returns it back to the client. So although the semantics in Rack are modelled after HTTP, it never actually sees "raw" HTTP.

Comment: Also, to "execute a Rack app directly", you also use an application server like Webrick. In that regard, the lines between a "webserver" and an "application server" are kind of blurry. since both types might parse HTTP and hand the requests over to a content handler using a different protocol (like Rack, CGI, WSGI, ...)

Comment: @HolgerJust You’re right, of course; I oversimplified. Will fix when I’m back at a keyboard.

Comment: Actually, puma is an application server to manage process and memory, right? Thank you for your comprehensive explanation.

Comment: WSCH is kind of interface between web server and application server in python, right? So what is module used for application server in python? I google it, the result show the Django or CherryPy. But they are web framework. What is underlying package used for application server in these web framework?

Comment: WSCH is a radio station. WSGI is something similar to Rack, for Python. Django and CherryPy are Python web frameworks similar to Ruby’s Rails and Sinatra, respectively.

Comment: Are there Python's package similar to Ruby's Puma, Unicorn?